# Prestashop admin new order email sometimes missing

Tags: email, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Need help - my prestashop sometimes not sending new order admin emails. They are not in the email logs in backoffice, and not in the spam folder in email. 
I also noticed a pattern, that for new orders with just numbers in reference email are generating, but i'm not receiving admin emails for orders with random letters in reference, like this:

[image]

Other emails, such as order confirmation and payment confirmation are generating for every order and they are received by customers.
Is there any way to change this order reference to just numbers or any other way to deal with email problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing module named "Email Alerts". You can install this module and you can setup notification accordingly.

Hope this helps you !!! :)

Here is the module links: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/is666weeq6qhcug/mailalerts.zip?dl=0
https://github.com/PrestaShop/mailalerts

Comment: thank you for your answer. Yes, i have installed this module, and some email are still not generating

Comment: Can you please share your configuration setting screen capture?